# Fail to generate Interactive Plot on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, plotly, cufflinks

I am trying to generate Interactive Plot on Jupyter Notebook with Plotly and Cufflinks. But when I run the code, there is an empty space for the figure but no actual plot. Please see the code below.

Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cufflinks as cf
import plotly
import plotly.offline as plyo
%matplotlib inline
plt.ion()


a=np.random.standard_normal((250,5)).cumsum(axis=0)
index=pd.date_range('2019-1-1', freq='B', periods=len(a))
df=pd.DataFrame(100+5*a, columns=list('abcde'), index=index)
plyo.iplot(df.iplot(asFigure=True), image='png',filename='ply_01')
```

Comment: are you using `jupyter` in colab or on your local machine ?

Comment: your code works just fine. Could you please tell me your `python`, `cufflinks` and `plotly` version ?

Comment: @JayPatel, I have the following versions: Python:3.9.1, cufflinks:0.17.3 and plotly: 4.14.3

Comment: Can you try running this same code in google colab and see if that works ? Because this code does work fine on my local machine and on colab as well i tested it.

Comment: Yes, it runs on Colab indeed. I'll close the issue now. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: PS- Will investigate the Jupyter issue separately.